# How do I process RAW images with the command line in Linux?

Tags: command-line, images, camera-raw

I want to be able to manipulate RAW images from the Linux command line, like so:

```
cat raw1.img | raw2jpg -w 640 -h 480 -pitch 1024 -pixelformat R8G8B8

tr='transpose -pitch 1024 -depth 24'
cat <(cat raw1.img | $tr) <(cat raw2.img | $tr) | transpose -pitch 480 >x-merge.img

cat gamebitmap.dat | (
    w=`readint32`
    h=`readint32`
    raw2png -w $w -h $h -depth 24 -pixelformat R8G8B8
) | png2svg -extractoutline -fuzzy -error 8 -smooth
```

Obviously I've made up the `raw2png`, `raw2jpg` and `transpose` programs.

Does ImageMagick support operations like this with camera RAW files? If not, is there any other way I can manipulate these images from the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which type of raw file?

There's Sony, Kodak, Nikon, Olympus, etc.  [Full list](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php)

Have you tried `convert` from ImageMagick, e.g.

```
convert raw1.img raw1.jpg
```

What does

```
file raw1.img
```

say?

What happens if you rename raw1.img to one of the extensions listed in the link, e.g. raw1.arw or raw1.crw?

Comment: The raw files are uncompressed bitmap, they don't have any file header, there width/height/depth are unknown. `file ...` show them as data files. However, in the Full List, `RGB`, `RGBA`, 'CMYK` formats fit my need. Thanks!